# How to perform automated deployment - with a Pull model

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, teamcity, msdeploy

We're currently doing continuous deployment to our dev/qa servers, and manually triggered automated deployment to our production boxes. Currently we're using TeamCity/PowerShell/MsDeploy. We now have a requirement to deploy to a server that sits on an external network, on which the target server cannot be accessed externally. Instead, it will have to "call home" for updates - and presumably then push the results back if it succeeds or not.

I'm thinking we could write a service that requests a particular URL on our build server with delivers the artifacts that would have been used for deployment, pull that down - and then fire off the build script.

However, I'm not entirely sure how we'd deal with updating the updater, and failures when they occur. Does anyone have any recommendations on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a release repository. The build server pushes files into it and each deploy job pulls from it. This would neatly decouple the two processes.

A release repository could be as simple as a shared NAS, or something more sophisticated such as the [Nexus repository manager](http://nexus.sonatype.org/).